# Access subclass properties in Criteria Builder JPA

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I am trying to use the JPA's 2.0 criteria query with the underlying implementation of Hibernate. I am having issues while trying to access properties of subclass in the where clause..

Following are brief description of the entities:

```
   - Class A (which is a Entity & a Table by itself)
   - Class B (which is a Entity & a Table by itself)
   - Class A has OneToMany relationship with B
   - Class AB & BA are child classes of B (Both are entities but are not mapped to any tables. It holds few properties specific to it.)
   - Let us suppose both classes AB & BA has a property '''symbol'''
```

Now comes the criteria query:

```
CriteriaBuilder qb = futuresEntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<A> query = qb.createQuery(A.class);
Root<A> a = query.from(A.class);
Join<A,B> b = a.joinSet("aLegs", JoinType.INNER);
```

Now when I form the predicates:

```
predicate=qb.and(qb.equal(a.get("id").get("accountId"), "1234"));
predicate=qb.and(predicate,b.get("symbol").in(input.getSymbol()));
```

----- The above line does not work at run time as b does not hold the reference to symbol. only child classes AB & BA holds it..

How do i access the properties of child classes in this query ? I have to Include both AB & BA for the symbol predicate.

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Can anybody please help me with this? I have been stuck with this issue for sometime now. I guess JPA 2.1 has something as TREAT AS which might help me to resolve this issue but I am stuck with JPA 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JPA's 2.0 [`Epression#as()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html#as%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
Path bCasted = (Path)b.as(AB.class);
Predicate newCastedPredicate = bCasted.get("symbol").in(input.getSymbol());
```

But I think that you need to peform the above operation separately and recursively for each of the needed subclasses.

**Unrelated:** pay attention that the `in` predicate accepts either a Collection or an Expression. Have a look at the javadoc in the page linked above.

Comment: Thanks @perissf: But b.as(AB.class) returns an expression and I am getting the below ClassCast Exception when I try to cast it to Path. 

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.expression.function.CastFunction cannot be cast to javax.persistence.criteria.Path

Can you please let me know how do I go about getting the value from an expression?

Comment: From this [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.1.0/JPAQueryEnhancements#Query_Casting) it seems that EclipseLink has enhanced this method with respect to JPA 2.0 specs. If I understand well, the _normal_ behavior is get when changing the line into `Path<AB> bCasted = b.as(AB.Class);`. can you try it?

Comment: I guess EclipseLink implementation supports the casting to Path but Hibernate implemention does not support the same. I ran into the above mentioned exception at runtime while trying to do so.